# Switching from scrartcl to article

Tags: koma-script, article

I help run a (science) summer camp where participants write up their reports in LaTeX.  We have a custom class file that's used to format the reports and make it easier for us to produce a book, ready for printing.  It fixes things like layout, footers/headers and some custom commands for project titles and so on.  Most of the major layout options are controlled using `fancyhdr`.

Currently we're using the `scrartcl` class for layout.  As we can't make people install LaTeX prior to the camp, let alone enforce which packages they have installed, we find that we have to provide hardcopies of this (and its dependencies).  We don't have reliable access to the internet (and part of the camp is encouraging disconnection from it!) so we can't just grab it using a package manager.

This is largely legacy and nobody's bothered to sift through the class to update it.  It's irritating having to provide people with multiple files (`scrartcl, scrfile, typearea, etc`) instead of one.  We've tried assuming they're already installed and every now and again someone can't compile their report which is a pain.

I understand that KOMA-script has some lean towards European standards for typesetting - we are based in Europe so this makes sense.  Are there any significant differences to using plain old `article`?

I've tried exporting documents using each style, but I can't see anything obvious aside from slightly different heading size and spacing.  Participants don't usually have time to learn anything particularly complicated about LaTeX so use of esoteric environments or commands rarely comes up. 99% of the time it's simple things: equations, sections, figures and a bibliography.

I also had a look at the documentation for KOMA-Script and there seems to be plenty of tweaks mentioned for optimal page layout, but there wasn't any difference at all when I tried on some sample files.

Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I think it would be better to make them use KOMA-script in the first place (you now some of the benefits). You can put a complete image of TeX Live on usb sticks and make the install by mounting the stick (or rather the iso). This ensures all participants to have the same package versions etc. I think this is the best and cleanest way (tough a bit of effort is needed).

Comment: Btw, KOMA comes with it's own package for headers and footers called `scrlayer-scrpage`. `Fancyhdr` is not as reliable with KOMA classes.

Comment: Thanks!

Sure, obviously the ideal would be to let LaTeX take care of everything - it may be that the easiest way is to force everyone to upgrade their LaTeX installs.  

We do provide installers for Mac/Win since we can't guarantee net access.  I assume KOMA should be included (our class file was last updated in 2002 so perhaps it wasn't then!) in TeX Live these days?

Comment: Yes, it is included in TeX Live, but you can get the very last version of KOMA by setting up an extra rep downloading it directly from the authors webspace.

Comment: Why don't you provide TeX Live 2014 on DVD for your participants? It's all included...

Comment: We do.  However not all participants are new, some have TeX already installed from other places, some have minimal installations, etc.  The list goes on, we have ~70 people with every type of system under the sun.

It sounds like this should be easy, but trust me - you delete the class files that get distributed with the main camp class and people have problems.

None of this really answers the question though - if I can't see a difference when we use KOMA, what's wrong with article?

Comment: To answer the Q: Depends on how you used KOMA. If you used it like *plain old article* there aren't many noticable differences. The typearea is defferent, titles are set differently. That's the first two differences coming to mind. Did you use `\addsec` or changed any font elements using `\addtokomafont`? Any documentclass options like `parskip` or `listof=totoc`? You will get errors or warnings when using article with those elements.

Comment: It is your class. You should know if you are using special features of the koma classes. But I would try to enforce system update. They are a lot of packages where a current version is sensible like  siunitx, tikz, pgfplots, biblatex, hyperref ...

Comment: Well, this is the point: it's not my class, I didn't write it.  It was last updated in 2002, well before any of the current users (including me) had anything to do with the organisation.  It's been used happily for the last 12 years for over a thousand documents hence no one checked or knew enough about TeX to check.

As far as I can tell none of the options are KOMA specific. I'm just torn between keeping KOMA and attempting to reconcile all the layout packages, e.g. titlesec and fancyhdr, vs switching back to article and avoiding potential incompatibility down the road.

Comment: Both `titlesec` and `fancyhdr` shouldn't be used with KOMA. KOMA itself was updated heavily in the past 10 years. Even the standard article class got updated. Have a look into the newest KOMA-script manual to see more details.